# Adding new System Call to Linux Kernel 3.13 on 64 bit system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to add a simple `helloworld` System Call to `kernel 3.13.0-37-generic` on 64 bit system.

**I'll try to show what I did so far step by step :**

**1- I've downloaded kernel source by :**

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic
```

After that, kernel source files extracted to `/usr/src/`

**2- Define a new system call `sys_hello()` :**

I've created a directory with `hello` name in the kernel source directory in `/usr/src/linux-3.13/`

And I created a `hello.c` file in `hello` directory with below content :

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_hello(void)
{
        printk(“Hello world\n”);
        return 0;
}
```

Then I created a `Makefile` in the hello directory with following content :

```
obj-y := hello.o
```

**3- Add the hello directory to the kernel’s Makefile**

I changed following line in `/usr/src/linux-3.13/Makefile`:

```
core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/
```

to :

```
core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ hello/
```

**4- Add the new system call `sys_hello()` into the system call table (syscall_64.tbl file)**

Because I'm using 64 bit system, I need to alter the `syscall_64.tbl` file in :

```
/usr/src/linux-3.13/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl
```

Added the following line in the end of the file :

-Last line number was `313`

```
314     common    hello    sys_hello
```

**5- Add the new system call `sys_hello()` in the system call header file**

```
vim /usr/src/linux-3.13/include/linux/syscalls.h
```

I've added the following line to the end of the file just before the #endif  statement at the very bottom :

```
asmlinkage long sys_hello(void);
```

**6- Compiling this kernel on my system**

To configure the kernel I tried the following command :

```
sudo make menuconfig
```

After above command a pop up window came up and I made sure that `ext4` was selected and then `save`.

Then :

```
# cd /usr/src/linux-3.13/
# make
```

It tooks 2~3 hours.

After that :

```
# make modules_install install
```

After that, I rebooted my system.

**7- Test the system call (Problem Is Here)**

After reboot, I created a file with name `hello.c` in home folder with following content :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
         long int amma = syscall(314); // 314 is the number of sys_hello line in `syscall_64.tbl`
         printf(“System call sys_hello returned %ld\n”, amma);
         return 0;
}
```

Then :

```
# gcc hello.c
# ./a.out
```

The output is :

```
System call sys_hello returned -1
```

Problem exactly is `-1`. It must return `0` not `-1`.

Seems like `sys_hello` doesn't added  to Kernel System Call.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look in the kernel log or check uname to make sure you are running your new build.  Maybe check the system.map to see if your addition was included in the kernel.

Comment: I can't figure it out by `uname` cause before/after kernel is same (Both are `kernel 3.13.0-37-generic`).

Comment: There is no log in `dmesg` that related to `sys_hello` system call !

Comment: Doesn't your kernel output include when it was built?  I wasn't suggesting you look there for evidence of your function, but rather for evidence that you are in fact running your new build.  Then separately make some checks to see if your new build picked up your code at all.

Comment: Check also  `/proc/version`

Comment: Learn about `make-kpkg` to build a kernel, and pass `-j 4` to `make-kpkg` or to `make` when building it.

Comment: @HamedKamrava What shall I do to invoke the system call by using something like hello(), but not the function syscall(XXX)?

Comment: @HamedKamrava I am having the same problem with kernel 4.12.10, can you have a look to this please:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141888/new-implemented-syscall-for-linux-kernel-4-12-10-returning-1/46142961?noredirect=1#comment79248343_46142961

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was from step 6  to last step (Compile Kernel).

After step 5, we have to do following steps :

**6- Compiling this kernel on my system**

To configure the kernel I tried the following command :

```
# make menuconfig
```

After above command a pop up window came up and I made sure that ext4 was selected and then save.

Then to create `DEB` file from new kernel we have to :

```
# make -j 5 KDEB_PKGVERSION=1.arbitrary-name deb-pkg
```

It will create some `deb` files in `/usr/src/`.

After that we need to install them :

```
# dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

It will install new kernel on your system.

Now, reboot your system. After system rebooted you can find out whether new kernel is installed or not :

```
$ uname -r
```

And if you want to know your new System Call added to kernel or not just type :

```
$ cat /proc/kallsyms | grep <system call name>
```

In my case :

```
$ cat /proc/kallsyms | grep hello
```

Following output indicates that your System Call successfully added to the Kernel :

```
0000000000000000 T sys_hello
```

Comment: Very nicely questioned and answered !