# Adding a new system call Linux 5-9.8 and make it appear on boot screen

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to add a new system call to linux -5.9.8 for this I've been following this tutorial [from a prev question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720644/adding-new-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-13-on-64-bit-system) and this one [and this from a guide](https://dev.to/jasper/adding-a-system-call-to-the-linux-kernel-5-8-1-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-2ga8) they are both really similar and everything does work as intended BUT to get the system call to show with `dmesg` we get to compile the following code **after boot up**:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define __NR_identity 440

long identity_syscall(void)
{
    return syscall(__NR_identity);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long activity;
    activity = identity_syscall();

    if(activity < 0)
    {
        perror("Sorry. Your system call appears to have failed.");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Congratulations! Your system call is functional. Run the command dmesg in the terminal and find out!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code does in fact add the message to `dmesg` but it does it after boot up and I need to run the code everytime, how should I go to actually make my system call appear on the boot up screen and not later, what file should I edit to make it happen?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "boot up screen". Is it a stage when you select OS to load? The Linux kernel is not loaded at this stage and syscalls are non-functional.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to merely display some sort of message at system startup time, you don't need a system call but rather a kernel module statically linked or dynamically loaded.

In the file where you define the system call, you can add an "init" routine which will be called by the kernel at startup. To make it, the kernel build chain uses "__init" section identifier to gather all the initialization entry points into a dedicated section. Then, in the boot procedure, all the functions from this section are called. You can try something like the following from your [example](https://dev.to/jasper/adding-a-system-call-to-the-linux-kernel-5-8-1-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-2ga8) (I didn't tried it !):

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

SYSCALL_DEFINE0(identity)

{
    printk("I am Jihan Jasper Al-rashid.\n");
    return 0;
}

void __init identity_entry(void)
{
  printk("Boot message from identity\n");
}
```